# Firebase Callable Cloud Function CORS Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

The following is the **client side code** to call the cloud function:

```
var getShippingRate = firebase
            .functions()
            .httpsCallable("shippo-generateShippingRate");
          getShippingRate({ address: shippo })
            .then(function(result) {
              // Read result of the Cloud Function.
              console.log("THE SHIPPING RATES", result.data.shipment);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              // Getting the Error details.
              console.log("ERROR SHIPPING: ", error);
              var code = error.code;
              var message = error.message;
              var details = error.details;
            });
```

**The cloud function:**

```
exports.generateShippingRate = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
const customer_address = data.address;

return generateShipmentObject(customer_address);
});
```

**`generateshipmentObject` returns this:**

```
shippo.shipment.create(
{
  address_from: addressFrom,
  address_to: addressTo,
  parcels: [parcel],
  async: true
},
(err, shipment) => {
  // asynchronously called
  if (err) {
    return { error: err };
  } else {
    return { result: shipment };
  }
}
```

I get the standard CORS Error, but a callable Cloud Function should handle this automatically:

*Access to fetch at ... from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy:*

**EDIT**

I'm using `firebase serve --only hosting` to test on localhost.

The Cloud Functions are deployed with `firebase deploy --only funtions`

I'm calling other similar Cloud Functions on the same site which do not have that issue.

Comment: Are you using the Firebase local emulator?  If so, could you edit the question to say more about that setup, and how we might be able to reproduce your situation?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Have you confirmed that it’s a 200 OK success response rather than 4xx or 5xx error?

Comment: @sideshowbarker There is no response since the `Preflight response is not successful` due to CORS issue

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm using `firebase serve --only hosting` to test on localhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temp fix:

In the cloud console functions page, select a function to show the info panel. In the permissions tab, select ADD MEMBER. In the new members field, type allUsers. In the roles drop down, select cloud functions, then cloud functions invoker, and save.

It actually sort of makes sense for a function to have restricted permissions when it's first created, however I'm used to the default permissions being present, so it's a bug (or new feature) that definitely threw me off. Of course this doesn't fix the underlying problem, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this! I also found a caution about it here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions "Caution: New HTTP and HTTP callable functions deployed with any Firebase CLI lower than version 7.7.0 are private by default and throw HTTP 403 errors when invoked. Either explicitly make these functions public, or update your Firebase CLI before you deploy any new functions."

Comment: For complementing this answer, this is available on https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation